# How to setup Rotativa.aspnetcore Configuration in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, rotativa

How to add Rotativa.aspnetcore configuration in `Program.cs` instead of `RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env);` that was in `Startup.cs` in .NET 5 and below?

What I have tried this in `Program.cs`:

```
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .Net 5 or below version, the configure method like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IWebHostEnvironment env,
                      IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime,
                      IService service)
{
    //........
}
```

In .NET 6, there are a few common services available as top level properties on `WebApplication` and additional services need to be manually resolved from the `IServiceProvider` via `WebApplication.Services`.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService, Service>();

var app = builder.Build();

IService service = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IService>();
ILogger logger = app.Logger;
IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime = app.Lifetime;
IWebHostEnvironment env = app.Environment;

//.....
```

**So in your project, You can just configure like this**:

```
IWebHostEnvironment env = app.Environment;
RotativaConfiguration.Setup((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment)env);
```

For more information on the difference between the configuration files in `.Net 6` and `other version`, please refer to [this link](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/0e0372c3c1d895c3ce195ba983b1e03d)

Comment: Please ensure that the Rotativa folder exists where the executable files are stored. In my-case exe was not downloaded due to wwwroot folder was missing